Interpreting Derivatives with Defined Values Beyond Domain
Suppose we have the following function:
$$
f(x) = \ln(x)
$$
$f(x)$ has a domain of $(0, \infty)$.
However, consider its derivative:
$$
f'(x) = \frac{1}{x}
$$
Unlike the original function, the derivative's domain is not $(0, \infty)$ but instead $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$. A natural question is to ask what the derivative means in the intervals where the function is not defined but the derivative is.

You might like to read about analytic continuation.  Caution: in calculus of a real variable, there "is no" complex plane to extend out onto -- the functions aren't defined there, limits aren't defined there so derivatives, sums, and integrals aren't defined there.  Even the complex square root is a different function than the real square root.

It doesn't mean anything, literally. Consider the function $f(x) = (\ln x)' $.You can describe it as $f: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \backslash (-\infty , 0] $

You can extend $f$ to the function $\bar f$ defined on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ in a piecewise manner:
$$
\bar f(x) = \begin{cases}
\ln(x), & x>0 \\
\ln(-x), & x<0. 
\end{cases}
$$
Remember that a function is not just a formula, but actually consists of three things:

domain: a set of inputs,
codomain: a set containing outputs, and
rule: an explicit description of how each input gets converted to a unique output.

So this extended function $\bar f$ agrees with $f$ everywhere that $f$ is defined. In symbols $\bar f(x) = f(x)$ for all $x > 0$, but it's also defined elsewhere.
It's easy to verify that $\bar f'(x) = \smash[b]{\dfrac1x}$ for all $x \neq 0$, which makes it a better antiderivative of the reciprocal function.

Note: the absolute value function has an analogous piecewise definition for nonzero numbers, namely
$$
|x| = \begin{cases}
x, & x>0 \\
-x, & x<0. 
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore, it's common to write
$$
\bar f(x) = \ln\bigl(|x|\bigr), 
$$
or just $\ln|x|$ for brevity.

It's worth noting that we could go the other direction and restrict the domain of the reciprocal function to only positive numbers. Let's call this function $r$. So $r$ is only defined for $x > 0$ where $r(x) = \frac1x$. Then, with $f(x) = \ln(x)$ whose domain is also $(0, \infty)$, we would have $f'(x) = r(x)$.

All of this is to emphasize that functions aren't just formulas, but descriptions of transforming elements of a set into elements of another set.
